# Why does my same unchanged webscraping code keep showing different things each time I run it?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, playwright-python

This is my code that web scrapes multiple tables with horse data from this website. "https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/raCing/RaceCard.aspx?RaceDate=2023/04/15&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1" What its supposed to do is click on each horse from the website, which will lead it to a popup window where it should click on the "Show All" button and print out the table shown.

However, each time I run it, something different happens. Sometimes only half the table is printed, sometimes only one row of sometimes it works perfectly fine. Why is this happening?

````
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from playwright.sync_api import Playwright, sync_playwright, expect
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book("jockeyclub.xlsx")
rc1 = wb.sheets['Race Card 1']

#A list of the horses on the race card is already printed out on the Excel Spreadsheet

rownum = 6
tablerow = 20

#the rownum variable will determine which horse from which row of the spreadsheet should be set as a variable. 
#The program will then store the horse name as a variable, find the horse name on the website and click on it.

def scrape_ranking(url, sheet_name):
    with sync_playwright() as p:
        global rownum
        global tablerow

        horse_name = rc1.range('E' + str(rownum)).value
        print(horse_name)
        
        browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = browser.new_page()
        page.goto(url)

        with page.expect_popup() as popup_info:
            page.click('text="%s"' %horse_name)

        print("clicked on horse name")

        popup = popup_info.value
        popup.wait_for_load_state("domcontentloaded")

        popup.get_by_alt_text("Show All").click()
        print("clicked show all")

        html = popup.content()
        browser.close()

    tables = pd.read_html(html)
    df = tables[7]
    print(df)

    rc1.range('A' + str(tablerow-1)).value = horse_name

    with pd.ExcelWriter("jockeyclub.xlsx", engine="openpyxl", mode='a', if_sheet_exists='overlay') as writer:
        df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False, startrow=tablerow)

    tablerow = tablerow + 60      #This variable is to space out the tables
    rownum=rownum+1

while rownum <= 13:
    url_1 = ('https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/English/raCing/RaceCard.aspx?RaceDate=2023/04/15&Racecourse=ST&RaceNo=1%27)
    scrape_ranking(url_1, "Race Card 1")```
````

Comment: Maybe try `popup.wait_for_load_state("domcontentloaded")` before `popup.content()`. If that doesn't work, try `popup.wait_for_load_state("networkidle")`.